# Reading only data from excel skipping formula using java

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel workbook where sheet2 contains defined names and sheet 1 is populated based on formulae and data validations.

I need to read sheet1 data using java . When I try fileInputstream and create a new sheet from sheet1 it is creating with formula also hence it is not creating it properly.

Is there a way to directly create a new sheet with only data skipping all formulae?

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: I saved it as csv and uploaded it. Sorry for the dumb question

Answer (score 1):

Creating an Excel file using `FileInputStream` will simply create a copy of the relevant file. What you need to do is something different, specific to Excel, so standard file operations are no good. Take a look at either [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org) or [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org), both of which can read and manipulate Microsoft Office files.

For example, it's trivial for a piece of docx4j code to iterate a specified worksheet, and extract / clone cell values, ignoring underlying formula.